# How to join tables together - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

This is a SQL question

I have two tables I need to join together, using the inner join syntax. One named Entry, and the other named prize. I need to list the `event_id, horse_id, place, money`.

```
ENTRY (TABLE NAME)
COLUMNS IN TABLE ENTRY:
Event_id,
Horse_id
Place

PRIZE (TABLE NAME)
COLUMNS IN TABLE PRIZE:
Event_id,
Place,
Money
```

This is as far as I have got, I just can't get my head around it.

```
SELECT event_id, horse_id, place
FROM ENTRY INNER JOIN PRIZE
ON ENTRY.money = PRIZE.money
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT e.Event_id, e.Horse_id, e.place, p.money

FROM ENTRY e join Prize p

ON e.Event_id = p.Event_id

where e.place = p.place;
```

The e and p are used as aliases for the tables to avoid unreadable sql because of long table names.

using the e. or p. you will select the field for that table because it is possible that both tables have a field with the same name so there will be issues when executing the statement

I added the e.place = p.place because if you don't you would be getting the results for every place for each event matched with every prize

for example you would get
Event 1 horse 1 place 1 prize 1
event 1 horse 1 place 1 prize 2
Event 1 horse 1 place 1 prize 3
event 1 horse 1 place 1 prize 4
etc... until you get every prize and this would be the same for every entry, assuming the event for the prize equals the event for the entry

Comment: I figure you need to get the event, horse, place and prize for each place in each race I think this is the correct way of getting every correct prize for each entry by place and event

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use alias to avoid ambiguity

```
select 
e.event_id,
e.horse_id,
e.place,
p.Money
from ENTRY e 
join PRIZE p on p.event_id = e.event_id
```